# Problem with a definition of $\succsim$-maximal element and $\succsim$-maximum

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I found in a book the following definition of $\succsim$-**maximal** element and $\succsim$-**maximum**, but I really don't see the difference between what is written in the book (I know the difference between those two concepts). Am I wrong?

Let $(X,\succsim )$ be a preordered set and $∅ = Y ⊆ X$. An element $x$ of $Y$ is said to be $\succsim$-**maximal** in $Y$ if there is no $y \in Y$ with $y \succ x$. If $x \succsim y $ for all $y \in Y$ , then $x$ is called the $\succsim$-**maximum** of $Y$.

Comment: I am sorry for the potential duplicate, but I did it _bona fide_, because I truly believed it was not a problem of my understanding of the definition and the implications of the definition, but some sort of typo or missing part in the paragraph of the book. I hope it is not a problem and thanks for pointing me other answers to this topic.

Comment: It is certainly no problem, but for future visitors it is good to have these questions interlinked, as they are asking about the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the negation:

1. Maximal element is one that there does **not** exist anyone strictly larger.
2. Maximum element is one that **every** element is smaller or equivalent to.

We have $\lnot\exists y\varphi(y,x)$ and $\forall y\varphi(x,y)$, where $\varphi(x,y)$ states $y\precsim x$.

Comment: That's how I rephrase the above definitions: **maximum:** $\forall y \in Y(x \succsim y)$; **maximal:** $ \neg \exists y\in Y (y \succ x)$. But, this should be like the maximum definition, because $\neg (y\succ x)$ is the same of $y\succsim x$.

Comment: Kolmin, you have an assumption that the order is total.

Comment: Honestly I am having troubles seeing why it is the case that I am assuming that in my idea, but thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

A maximum element is necessarily comparable with all the other elements. It is possible to have two different maximal elements which cannot be compared with each other.

To illustrate take the set of integers greater than $1$, and $a \succsim b$ defined as $b=ra$ for some positive integer $r$.

Then $2$ and $3$ are both maximal, but neither is a maximum.

Add $1$ to the set, and $1$ becomes the unique maximum.